# Ionic returning wrong response from HTTP POST

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, response

I have an extremely simple API, where it is possible to make a request to create a user by email, if it already existed, returns an error.
The problem is that this API works normally, but not in Ionic. When I make the request to the URL, with a completely new user, it returns a response that it already exists, but when I see the database, it actually was created

**What I believe is happening:**
Ionic it is making a request, and after completing it, does another and shows me the result of the last.

Note: I used for this App, the "Super Template", I do not know if it can have a bug that is doing this, because I never had this problem.

**User.ts**

```
signup(accountInfo: any) {
this.api.post('create_user&name='+accountInfo.name+'&email=' + accountInfo.email + '&pass=' + Md5.hashStr (accountInfo.password),
  {},this.reqOpts).map((res) => res.json()).subscribe((resp)=>{
    console.log(resp);
  })
```

**Api.ts**

```
post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.url + endpoint, reqOpts);
```

I already tried adding the `.share()` in several places, and I did not succeed.

Comment: Use debugger to confirm if it's making multiple request & you can find out who's triggering it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you guard yourself against sending multiple requests with a boolean. Maybe that would be of some help. That can also help you with loading indicators and other things you may need while sending the request.

Sometimes even the user may click a couple of times and you don't need to send multiple requests, so you can just check if a request is in progress.

`isRequestSent: boolean = false;`

```
signup(accountInfo: any) {
    if(!this.isRequestSent) {
        this.isRequestSent = true;
        this.api.post('create_user&name='+accountInfo.name+'&email=' + accountInfo.email + '&pass=' + Md5.hashStr (accountInfo.password),{},this.reqOpts)
        .map((res) => res.json())
        .subscribe((resp)=>{
            console.log(resp);
            this.isRequestSent = false;
        }, (error: any) => {
            this.isRequestSent = false;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect, but the current problem is that the request that is being returned to me is always one with the result that the user already exists. The first request (for registration) is never returned

Comment: Hmm, then i think you should open the web inspector, go to the network tab, and see if 2 POST request are sent. 

(Caution: angular may send an OPTIONS request so you may think that 2 requests are sent, but only check if 2 POST requests are sent)

I suspect that this is a backend issue and not your fault.

Comment: Seeing on Network Tab, he's actually making two requests, but one Options, other POST